# Can't restart failed services

Tags: services, lighttpd

I have two processes in my Pi that are stuck in the failed status.
The output of `systemctl --failed` is:

```
● lighttpd.service             loaded failed failed Lighttpd Daemon
● wpa_supplicant.service loaded failed failed WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
```

When I try to restart one of them with this command `sudo systemctl restart lighttpd.service` I get:

```
Job for lighttpd.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status lighttpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And the output of `systemctl status lighttpd.service` is:

```
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Mon 2019-07-22 17:07:16 EEST; 2min 12s ago
  Process: 1628 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=killed, signal=SEGV)


Jul 22 17:07:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 22 17:07:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jul 22 17:07:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 22 17:07:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Lighttpd Daemon.
Jul 22 17:07:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 22 17:07:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Lighttpd Daemon.
Jul 22 17:07:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 22 17:07:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Comment: lighthttpd: This doesn't come installed on Rasbpian by default so might be a by-product from other work? If you don't need it, it's a security hazard and you can uninstall. If you do need to run a server, well that's a segfault so it would require further investigation. As root, you can try `gdb --args lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`, run, and look at the backtrace. Also `strace` may help. wpa_supplicant: that is likely failing for an entirely different reason so please post that service status log. Though if your WiFi is somehow working, seems like something may have replaced it?

Comment: What Raspberry Pi model and what operating system do you use?